# Create Dask Dataframe from Database (using Django QuerySets)

Tags: dataframe, django-queryset, dask

I am currently storing list of records under a column in a table, and creating a Pandas dataframe out of the QuerySet.

Is there any equivalent in Dask to create dataframe directly from Django QuerySet in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there is not an equivalent to directly do this in Dask. If you already have a pandas DataFrame from a QuerySet, you can convert this into a Dask DataFrame using [`from_pandas`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.from_pandas.html). Additionally, since QuerySet works on SQL databases, you may be able to use Dask's [`read_sql_table`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-sql.html#loading-from-sql-with-read-sql-table-or-read-sql-query).

Comment: What if my result from QuerySet is larger than RAM? Making a pandas DataFrame and then converting seems counterintuitive to the purpose of Dask.
read_sql_table doesn't work for my case, as I am not making a dataframe from a whole table rather I'm making on out of a single column that stores data in list of dict format.

Comment: Maybe you could save your result from QuerySet to disk and then read it in with Dask? Also, since you mention the data is a list of dictionaries, [Dask Bag](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/bag.html) may be useful.

Comment: Writing to disk seems logical but how do I write a QuerySet to disk in a way that dask can read a dataframe out of it later?

Comment: Dask [can create DataFrames](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-create.html) from a number of data storage formats (e.g. CSV, HDF, Apache Parquet, to name a few). It can also create Dask DataFrames from a Dask bag, which can be [created directly from text files](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/bag-creation.html#db-read-text).